# Synchronize Provisioning Profiles Across Multiple Macs

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, provisioning-profile

I currently have multiple mac machines that are used for iOS development that are regularly building apps from an SVN repository.  Every now and then there are new provisioning profiles, or provisioning profiles that are updated with new devices and currently I maintain them by installing the provisioning profile(s) onto each machine individually.  Is there any way that I can automatically sync the provisioning profiles across the multiple machines?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just check them into SVN?  You can make a separate directory, or just put them in the project workspace.

Comment: Even if they are checked into SVN, the only way that they are going to be recognized by Xcode at time of codesigning is if they are in the designated provisioning profiles directory (where Xcode places them).  That would be a good solution if I could tell Xcode to use provisioning profiles that are stored in a particular directory.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Write an applescript that will open the provisioning files in Xcode. You can call it from a shell script if you save it as an application.